# understanding glm::perspective matrix

Tags: graphics, 3d, glm-math

I'm trying to implement a simple 3d render. I have implemented a perspective projection matrix similar to `glm::perspective`. I have read that a perspective projection matrix transforms vertices such that after the perspective division, visible region, i.e., objects that lie inside the specified frustum fall in the range `[-1,1]`, but when I tested some values with a matrix returned by `glm::perspective` results are not similar to my understanding.

```
float nearPlane = 0.1f;
float farPlane = 100.0f;

auto per =
    glm::perspective(45.0f, (float)(window_width * 1.0 / window_height),
                        nearPlane, farPlane);
// z=nearplane
print(per * glm::vec4(1, -1, -0.1, 1));
// z=farplane
print(per * glm::vec4(1, -1, -100, 1));
// z between nearplane and farplane
print(per * glm::vec4(1, -1, -5, 1));
// z beyond far plane
print(per * glm::vec4(1, -1, -200, 1));
// z behind the camera
print(per * glm::vec4(1, -1, 0.1, 1));
// z between camera and near plane
print(per * glm::vec4(1, -1, -0.09, 1));
```

As per my understanding, if vertices have a z coordinate which lies towards positive z-direction from `nearPlane` then after perspective divide `z/w` value should be <-1 but as shown in the picture below it is not the case. what am I missing?

[image: output of above print statements]

Comment: Shouldn't you be using positive z-values as input?

Comment: @BDL i dont think thats an issue, because when i give nearPlane and far plane as input it is giving -1 and 1 respectively, also if that was the case second last print statement should have resulted is z-value in range [-1,1] but cleary that is not the case above

Comment: Sorry, you are right. But I probably don't understand your question then: In the three cases where the depth is between near and far, the z/w value is in range [-1, 1] (which is correct. In the other cases, the z/w value is outside of [-1, 1]. Which value exactly are you confused with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> as per my understanding if vertices has z coordinate which is lies towards positive z direction from nearPlane then after perspective divide z/w value should be <-1 but as shown in picture below it is not the case. what am i missing?

That's simply not the case. There is a singularity at z=0 (camera plane), and the sign of the function flips (camera is looking to the left; blue vertical line is the near clipping plane):

[image: graph]

Those values are still outside the `[-1,1]` range, telling us that they are outside the camera frustum and should be clipped accordingly.

You might be confused because you're thinking that "smaller z/w values mean that the point is closer to the camera". But that's true only in-front of the camera. In fact the depth buffer values matter only if the fragment isn't clipped -- i.e. in the `[-1,1]` range, where that relation happens to be correct.

Comment: Thank you that really helped me, actually, I faced this problem while trying to implement near-plane clipping. the vertex that is towards the positive z-axis from the near plane can have a z/w value both less than -1 and greater than 1, can you give me some idea  how can i implement clipping then?

Comment: @AayushNeupane you usually clip before doing the perspective divide for that reason; another reason is that when you clip you also need to interpolate the attributes in world space rather than device space.